# Separating numbers of a string array to a integer array

Tags: java

So I have a String array that has a number like "`1234567898765`" and I want to convert it to an int and assign each number to each index of an array of integers.
For example, `array[i]= "1234567898765"` and I want to do `arrayOfIntegers[0] = 1` , `arrayOfIntegers[1] = 2`, `arrayOfIntegers[2] = 3`, ect... How can I do that?

Comment: Can you add the code that shows your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class  StringTest {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String input = "123456789765";
        int [] arrayOfInts = new int [input.length() ];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ ) {
            arrayOfInts[i] = Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```